# Handling Server-side RtmpConnection.Invoke() when connecting with NetConnection as a client using FluorineFx

Tags: c#, .net, rtmp, fluorinefx

I am trying to create a basic console app in order to stress test our FluorineFx based flash remoting server.

I can connect fine but the server method I am calling invokes this client-side function:

```
connection.Invoke("onServerDataPush", new string[] { "someParam", "anotherParam" });
```

I am struggling to find out how I can expose this method to the connection. The NetConnection.Call() method allow you to pass in a callback but the result of this is always null and the NetConnection call fails with the following error:

```
Could not find a suitable method with name onServerDataPush
```

Here is my client-side code:

```
class Program
{
    private NetConnection _netConnection;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.Connect();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        _netConnection = new NetConnection();
        _netConnection.ObjectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
        _netConnection.OnConnect += netConnection_OnConnect;
        _netConnection.NetStatus += netConnection_NetStatus;
        _netConnection.Connect("rtmp://localhost:1935/MyApplication");
    }

    void netConnection_OnConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var responder = new Responder<object>(x =>
                                                  {
                                                      var test = x;
                                                  });

        //The NetConnection object is connected now
        _netConnection.Call("MyServerMethod", responder, "someParameter");
    }
    void netConnection_NetStatus(object sender, NetStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        string level = e.Info["level"] as string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging through `RtmpClient` line 308 finally allowed me to solve this.

You must set the `NetConnection.Client` property to the class that contains a method of the same signature as the one being invoked by the server (in my case `this` as the method is in the Program class).

```
    public void onServerDataPush(string type, string json)
    {

    }
```

FluorineFx then calls the method using reflection.